# Magento 2 addStoreFilter is not working

Tags: magento2

Here is my code

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\InventoryManagement\Helper\Product;

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: abbas
 * Date: 17. 7. 14
 * Time: 오후 4:02
 */

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Inventory extends AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;


    /**
     * Status constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return Store
     */
    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = 2;//(int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId);
    }



    public function getInventory($storeCode){
        try {
            $result = array();

            $store = $this->_getStore();

            $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
                'sku'
            )->addAttributeToSelect(
                'name'
            )->addAttributeToSelect(
                'attribute_set_id'
            )->addAttributeToSelect(
                'type_id'
            )->setStore(
                $store
            );

            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);

            $i = 0;
            /**
             * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
             */
            foreach ($collection as $product){
                if($product->getData('transferred'))
                {
                   continue;
                }
                $result[] = $i;
                $i++;
            }
        }
        catch (\Exception $e){
            $success = false;
            if($product) {
                $result = $e->getMessage() . ' == ' . $product->getSku();
            }else{
                $result = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        return $result;

    }


}
```

It is a very simple code but here for collection it is returning all products and not applying the store filter.

Can you please let me know what is the issue here? I am using the Magento 2.2.5

Answer (score 1):

EG, to get all products for the current store:

Using `addStoreFilter()` you can get store ID or `Store` object as a parameter, see
`Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` and find 
 `addStoreFilter()` you can take refrance from there so you get solution what you doing wrong in your code.

Your filter code look like this if you get product collection.

```
public function getProducts(){
    return $this->collection->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore()); 
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I am using it in a helper which I am calling form the controller.

Comment: For that you have to inject helper in construct using `\{Vendor}\{Module}\Helper\Data $helperData`  and call your function in controller using like `$this->helperData-><functionName>();`

Comment: Yes I have done like this. I have one question. It is not possible to list the products using store id regardless of store?

Comment: I am not try this way but `->getStore()` will return current store so i think it will also return store id.

Comment: Thank You Chirag I have achieved it by using the addWebsiteFilter(). So first I use $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeCode) and then addWebsiteFilter() to the collection.

Comment: Welcome, Ohh how can i forgot this to pass `addWebsiteFilter()` :)

Comment: I have voted to your comments.

Comment: Thanks voted to comment does not get any rewards, for that to voted question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add just store id like

```
            $storeId=1;
            $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->setStoreId(
                $storeId
            )->addStoreFilter($storeId)
             ->addAttributeToSelect(
                'sku'
            )->addAttributeToSelect(
                'name'
            )->addAttributeToSelect(
                'attribute_set_id'
            )->addAttributeToSelect(
                'type_id'
            );
```

Comment: I have tested it like this also. even with store code but not working.

Comment: Ok, but make sure Is it a case like you have all products in both stores, isn't it?

Comment: When I filter the products from admin panel at Catalog -> Products -> Filters. It filter the products correctly. Is it a right way to know the products in a specific store?

Comment: can you try with my updated answer?

Comment: I have tested it but still returning all products. :(

Comment: One very amazing thing to confirm whether this code is working I also check in other projects. But in all projects returning all products.

Comment: Thank You @Hit I have achieved it by using the addWebsiteFilter(). So first I use $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeCode) and then addWebsiteFilter() to the collection.

Comment: @Abbas, it great that you have found the solution. Please share your solution as separate answer  that can help someone else.